# Need help showing that associativity works in a set of two symbols

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, axioms

Let $ \mathbb{P} = \left \{ \bullet , \blacksquare  \right \}$ be a set where elements $ \bullet \neq  \blacksquare$. For operation of addition in $\mathbb{P}$ we define:

$$\bullet + \bullet = \blacksquare$$
$$\blacksquare + \blacksquare = \blacksquare$$
$$\bullet + \blacksquare= \bullet$$
$$\blacksquare + \bullet = \bullet$$

Verify whether all axioms of addition apply for the set $\mathbb{P}$.

I got stuck showing that $A_2: \forall x,y, z\in \mathbb{P}: x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$ also works in the set  $\mathbb{P}$.

I managed to show that for $x=y=z=\bullet$ and $x=y=z=\blacksquare$ the association works just fine (it required nothing but the use of the definition of the addition (as stated above) plus $A_1 (commutativity)$ which I've managed to prove already. I got stuck at showing that if
$$x=\bullet=y \wedge z=\blacksquare $$ then $$\bullet+(\bullet+\blacksquare)=(\bullet+\bullet)+\blacksquare $$

So far my work, starting from the left side of the equation (I used merely the definition of addition in $\mathbb{P}$ and commutativity.

$$\bullet+(\bullet+\blacksquare)=\bullet+\blacksquare+(\bullet+\blacksquare)=\bullet+\blacksquare+\bullet=\bullet+\bullet+\blacksquare$$

so now if I put the $\bullet+\bullet$ in brackets, the problem will be solved. The question is: Can I do that? Can I just add brackets there?

Hilarious how something so trivial can be so puzzling.

Comment: Why not $\bullet+(\bullet+\blacksquare)=\bullet+\bullet=\blacksquare$ and $(\bullet+\bullet)+\blacksquare=\blacksquare+\blacksquare=\blacksquare$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, we are required to start at one end of the equation and then tweak the expression until we get the same expression that's on the other side of the equation - in my case, I started off with the left side of the equation with the aim to get the same expression that's on the right side

Comment: $\bullet + (\bullet + \blacksquare)= \bullet + \bullet = \blacksquare = \blacksquare + \blacksquare = (\bullet + \bullet)+ \blacksquare$

Comment: The structure defined here is just addition modulo $2$ with the circle being $1$ and the square being $0.$ So just replace the shapes with the numbers to make life easier.

Comment: There are only 8 cases here, total. It is very easy to just list them out and show that they each work.

Comment: I agree with @AdamRubinson. You could even prove that this structure is just $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+_2)$ with $0$ and $1$ having different names (i.e. they are isomorphic). Since $+_2$ is associative, the conclusion follows.